# Какими инструментами воспользоваться для манипуляции над окнами в системе?

Tags: python, linux, инструменты-разработчика

Появилась необходимость управления положением и размерами открытых окон в Linux. Начал гуглить оконные менеджеры для данной оси. Одним из первых понравившихся вариантов стал `wmctrl`, который написан на C.

Сам я пишу на пайтоне, но мне было бы удобно использовать команды терминала для управления окнами. В wmctrl как раз все так и организовано, мне понравился его функционал и я решил установить и попробовать. Потом я увидел год его выпуска и понял, что скорее всего возникнут проблемы)) По итогу он не видит половину открытых окон, и соответственно отпадает. При вводе `wmctrl -l`, в теории должен быть выведен список всех открытых окон, но я увидел только 1 из 4. Затем я нашел `qtile`, там возникла проблема с вэйландом, вероятно в силу моей криворукости.

Если кто нибудь пользовался подобными инструментами, можете посоветовать какой нибудь оптимальный вариант, который хотя бы корректно функционирует и не требует много зависимостей? Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы ищете легкий и эффективный оконный менеджер, которым можно управлять с помощью команд терминала, я рекомендую проверить [i3](https://i3wm.org/). Это плиточный оконный менеджер, который разработан таким образом, чтобы управляться с клавиатуры и легко настраиваться.

**Плюсы:**

1. i3 отлично поддерживает управление Windows с помощью инструментов командной строки и имеет простой формат файла конфигурации, который можно редактировать с помощью любого текстового редактора. Конфигурация по умолчанию довольно минимальна, но ее легко настроить в соответствии с вашими потребностями.
2. Одним из главных преимуществ i3 является его низкое потребление ресурсов. Он разработан таким образом, чтобы быть легким и эффективным, поэтому должен работать бесперебойно даже на более старом оборудовании. Он также отличается высокой стабильностью, благодаря большому и активному сообществу пользователей, которые постоянно тестируют и совершенствуют программное обеспечение.

Чтобы начать работу с i3, вы можете установить его через менеджер пакетов вашего дистрибутива Linux. После установки вы можете запустить его из своего дисплейного менеджера или запустив новый сеанс. В Интернете также доступно множество ресурсов, которые помогут вам научиться использовать и настраивать i3, включая официальную документацию и форумы сообщества.

Comment: Вы использовали его лично? Как он себя ведет с gnome?

Comment: Нет, сам не пользовался, но, насколько мне известно, по умолчанию он заменяет GNOME, поэтому вы не сможете использовать функции управления окнами GNOME по умолчанию. Однако, можно настроить i3 для работы вместе с GNOME. В целом, i3 и GNOME могут довольно хорошо работать вместе. Однако важно отметить, что пользовательский интерфейс i3 сильно отличается от GNOME, поэтому по мере адаптации к новому рабочему процессу может возникнуть необходимость в обучении.

Comment: Вообще, интересная реализация, я бы это использовал для пары отдельных компьютеров, где было бы плюсом сделать изолированную оконную среду без лишних элементов интерфейса. Но мне также нужна версия, которая бы не заменяла gnome и работала вместе с ним без дополнительных конфигураций. У вас нет на примете чего нибудь подобного?

Comment: Тут уже только гуглить. Могут подойти Xfce/xfwm4. Xfwm4 предоставляет многие из тех же функций управления окнами, что и i3, включая сочетания клавиш для перемещения и изменения размера окон, поддержку плиток и рабочих пространств. После установки вы можете переключиться на Xfce на экране входа в систему, выбрав "Xfce" или "Xubuntu" в качестве сеанса. В целом, Xfce и xfwm4 обеспечивают хороший баланс между функциональностью и простотой использования, и они должны хорошо работать вместе с GNOME, не требуя дополнительных конфигураций.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо за советы

Comment: Удачи с выбором! Надеюсь, помог вам)

Comment: Gnome поддерживает много функций управления окнами, не вижу смысла менять его на убогую Xfce. Зайдите в сочетания клавиш.

Answer (score 1):

Но если пишете на python, то стоит попробовать [Wnck](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#Wnck-3.0) именно для манипуляций с окнами

```
import time
import gi
gi.require_version('Gdk', '3.0')
gi.require_version('Wnck', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gdk, Wnck

Gdk.init([]) # нужно если не запускаете GLib.MainLoop или Gtk.main()
screen = Wnck.Screen.get_default()
screen.force_update() 

for window in screen.get_windows():
    print(f'{window.get_application().get_name()}: {window.get_name()}')
    time.sleep(0.200)
    window.activate(time.time())
```